# Improve performance of dynamically adding views in a layout

Tags: android, json, performance, android-layout

Working on app in which there are forms.
Forms have categories A, B, C and D.
I receive JSON of form from server and i have to convert it in Form(layout).
A form may contain one field or 100 depending on category.

***What i want:*** If there is a form with 100 fields how can improve performance of loading form.

***What I'm doing:*** I have loop of fields `size()` and checking each field type if it is MCQ(Multiple Choice Question) I have model of `RadioGroup` which add in `ViewGroup` in loop.

Comment: Pretty much a solid approach, loop over your models and create the appropriate view for each of them and add it to an existing view group

Comment: In case of creating layout of 100 fields may take more time, that will effect the app performance.

Answer (score 0):

`RecyclerView` my friend.

- It works well with list of models
- It supports having view types
- It will recycler views for you, no need to worry about memory

Comment: `RecyclerView` sounds good I'll try it. Hope so it will help me.

Answer (score 0):

@A.H.Khawer, Two approaches can be used.

1. One is what you are doing it assuming that json response that you are receiving is not controlled by you then keep on doing it. There are some libraries that can be used to reduce some boilerplate code from your side but they still do the same thing.
2. Second approach, if json response that you are getting is from your own Web API to make the forms dynamic and change without App update then in that case, try ReactNative (link: https://facebook.github.io/react-native/). 
   There are many more JS based Frameworks available to do the same.